# Unable to create Kubernetes Statefullset with PVC

Tags: kubernetes, azure-storage, kubernetes-pvc

Hello all i am trying to create a `StatefulSet` which has a PVC and StorageClass as Azurefileshare.
when i have created this my PVC is in pending state:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                 From                         Message
  ----     ------                ----                ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    51m                 persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "azurefile-standard-zrs2": could not get storage key for storage account : Failed to create storage account f38f8ede8e, error: storage.AccountsClient#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> Code="MaxStorageAccountsCountPerSubscriptionExceeded" Message="Subscription 0c767d4cf39 already contains 251 storage accounts in location westeurope and the maximum allowed is 250."
```

This is my manifest file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment2
  namespace: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backup
  serviceName: <SERVICE_NAME>
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backup
      annotations:
        backup.velero.io/backup-volumes: nginx-logs
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-logs1
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nginx-logs1
      containers:
      - image: base-debian:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "50m"
          limits:
            memory: "100Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var/log/nginx"
          name: nginx-logs1
          readOnly: false
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-logs1
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: backup
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: azurefile-standard-zrs2
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your yaml. It is not readable.

Comment: It says in the error message you posted: `Status= Code="MaxStorageAccountsCountPerSubscriptionExceeded" Message="Subscription 0c767d4cf39 already contains 251 storage accounts in location westeurope and the maximum allowed is 250."` You've reached the max number of storage accounts in a single subscription.

Answer (score 1):

As @**mmiking** pointed out in the comments section, you've reached the max number of storage accounts in a single subscription but **only** in the `westeurope` location.

You can see in the [Azure resource quotas documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-quotas#storage):

> Azure Storage has a limit of 250 storage accounts per region, per subscription. This limit includes both Standard and Premium storage accounts.

**NOTE:** This limit is per region per subscription. You are able to create 250 storage accounts in one region (e.g. `westeurope`) and you can still create another 250 storage accounts in a different region (e.g. `northeurope`) using the same subscription.

You can see your current storage account usage in a specific location using [az storage account show-usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_show_usage-examples) command:

```
$ az storage account show-usage --location <LOCATION_NAME> --out table --subscription <SUBSCRIPTION_ID>
CurrentValue    Limit    Unit
--------------  -------  ------
9               250      Count
```